# How to enumerate all possible subset with a fixed number of elements and sum of elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, combinations, partition

Given a set of possible values ***I***, how do I enumerate all possible subset vectors of length ***L*** such that the sum of the elements is ***k*** using Matlab?

Say ***I***=[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3], ***L***=3, and ***k***=4. Among the possible subsets are:
[0 1 3] [0 3 1] [1 0 3] [1 3 0] [3 0 1] [3 1 0]
[0 2 2] [2 0 2] [2 2 0] etc.

The solution I am implementing right now is this: Create *n* nested for-loops, where *n* is the number of unique elements in ***I***, the limits being from 0 to the maximum number of times element i can be used.

To make it run faster, I also modified the limits such that the sum will automatically be ***k*** without me checking in the end. In the process, I actually managed to remove one for-loop.

Such algorithm actually works, but my code really looks messy (Imagine if I have like 10 nested for-loops :O). More importantly, I find it difficult to automate the procedure for any set of inputs (***I***,***L***, ***k***) using this.

Can you think of any other way to do this? I think recursion will work fine here but I'm not very good in that regard and I find it hard to implement it in Matlab.

PS. I also tried combnk(I,L) and then check later on if the sum is k but it turns out that the code runs very slowly for big I and L.

Comment: Since the length of output vector of combnk is  `length(I)!/L!(length(I) – L)!` it's normal that this code runs slowly. We should find a way to add a new condition at each step that only take the part of I that respects the condition sum(I+Inewstep) <= k. But i'm not sure that it will be faster !

Comment: By the way you should have a look to: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM). You're not the first one who want to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way of using recursion (without any loops):

```
function [ comb ] = enumAll(I,L,K)

%//obtain a unique vector of I
I = unique(I);

%//base case: for the last place, enumerate all possibilites from 1:K
if L==1
    comb = (1:K).'; %//'
    return;
end

%//at each recursion step, find the (possibilities of the remaining positions), ..
suffixes = enumAll(I,L-1,K);
%//..and add the possibilities of this position with all of them
comb = reshape( repmat( (((1:K).')*(10^(L-1))).' , [length(suffixes) 1] ), [length(suffixes)*K 1] ) + repmat(suffixes,[K 1]);

end
```